# Showing All Products on the search results page

Tags: magento2, php, search, catalogsearch

It shows all products on the search results page even though there's pagination.
But the results are the same for all pages.
So the page speed is too slow and sometimes it's not working.

I checked this issue with two databases but it's working in the old database.
I also compared the settings between the two databases.
I think there's an issue in the settings but I can't find what is wrong.

Can you let me know what is causing this issue?

Thanks & Regards,
Gang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's related to the thrid party extensions.
In my case, it's related to the **Adroll** Extension.
I removed the **Adroll Extension block** from the search results page.
And now it works fine.